# Querying of Apex Properties

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, governorlimits, limitexception

In a controller for a visualforce page, that I have constructed, I have the following:

```
public User current_user {
    get {
        return [SELECT Name /*... other fields ...*/ FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    } set;
}
```

This is one of my variables that is not necessarily causing an issue, however I cannot share the other variables due to security reasons.  The variables are very similar in structure, however.

Here is an example method, called from the visualforce page:

```
public/pageReference void updateMethod() { 
    // ... arbitrary code that only modifies local variables ...
    OtherClass.someMethod(current_user.Name);
    // ... cont ...
}
```

I've noticed that my SOQL query count approaches the limit as updateMethod is called (regardless of the source, i.e. visualforce page / test method). My test methods have actually failed due to LimitExceptions because of this.

When variables with getter and setter methods are called, are the getters recompiled / reran?  If so, how would I go about preventing re-querying but also allowing the variable to be edited by the visualforce page?

Comment: In the getter method of the property have a If condition to check if it was already queried and if not then query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they re-run every time. A common pattern to avoid it is called **[`Lazy Loading`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)**:

```
public User current_user
{
    get
    {
        if (current_user == null)
        {
            current_user = [
                SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
            ];
        }
        return current_user;
    }
    private set;
}
```

This approach has a couple benefits:

- If you never call the getter, you never consume a query.
- If you call the getter a million times, it will still only perform the assignment logic once.

Comment: [Lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)

Comment: What is the significance of the private set;?  Just curious.

Comment: It means the page (or other classes) can't `set` the value, only the controller itself. You should use `private set` for all your properties as a default, and only use public setters when you know you need them.

Comment: adrian -- `current_user` vs `currentuser` typo

Comment: Its important to note that this pattern also requires the understanding that changes to the DB require you to NULL the property in order to get the updated values (or manually update the property). Ran into that before when I forgot something was lazy loaded and code did not function as expected because property was never updated.

Comment: Indeed, that bit of knowledge is quite useful. The pattern only requires that understanding if your data is volatile enough to need it. :) Probably not, in the OP case.

Comment: @eric and Adrian: i use this pattern all the time but condense the getter/setter to one  line: `get { return current_user == null ? current_user = [select name from USer where id = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1] : current_user;} private set;`  Note assignment has side effect of being the value of the ternary

Comment: I didn't realize assignment could be used in that way for types other than `Boolean`. TIL. Thanks @cropredy!

Comment: i don't take enough advantage of it myself; learned this from some other SFSE post. You can even do this: `String s;
String t = 'abc';
if ((s = t) == 'abc') system.debug(Logginglevel.info,s);`  `s` will have value `abc` - but I find this style of coding hard to read

Comment: Indeed you have to be careful with it. Pretty nifty for one-lining lazy-loads though. I will have to keep this in mind. @crop